# Count number of time each string appears in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, count

I have a database table with some rows...

[image]

...where often there will be several repeats of items in the `option_name` column. As you can see, there are more than one instance of Fish, Cat, Bird and Snake. This is expected and fine.

So I am returning these rows on the front end like this...

```
$poll_id    = 211;
$poll_table = $wpdb->prefix . "the_votes";
$poll_items = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT * 
    FROM $poll_table
    WHERE poll_id = $poll_id
");
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $poll_items as $poll_item ) {

    echo '<li>' . $poll_item->option_name . '</li>';

}
echo '</ul>';
```

...which will display like this:

- Cat
- Fish
- Bird
- Cat
- Snake
- Bird
- Cat
- Cat
- Fish
- Fish
- Fish
- Fish
- Fish
- Fish
- Fish
- Snake
- Cat

But what I actually need, is to make it so that there are no duplicates returned, and a count next to each. So it should show like this instead:

- Cat (5)
- Fish (8)
- Bird (2)
- Snake (2)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **group by** for it:

```
select option_name, count(id) as count from polls group by option_name;
```

Your code should look like this:

```
$poll_id    = 211
$poll_table = $wpdb->prefix . "the_votes";
$poll_items = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT count(id) as count, option_name 
    FROM $poll_table
    WHERE poll_id = $poll_id
    GROUP BY option_name
");
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $poll_items as $poll_item ) {

    echo '<li>' . $poll_item->option_name . '(' . $poll_item->count . ')</li>';

}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves half the problem. How do I get the counts next to each item?

Comment: I updated my answer, If it solved your problem do not forget to mark it as an answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM $poll_table
WHERE poll_id = $poll_id ***group by poll_id***

this method is used to filter the duplicate values

Comment: The poll_id field is the same, in this case it is 211 and select * part probably throw an error because sql can not aggregate all columns.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, **SELECT column_name, count(column_name)
FROM $poll_table
WHERE poll_id = $poll_id group by poll_id**. you can filter and get the id with their count. Instead of using *, you can use the column name.

Here in jquery, you can get the unique elements by using this **$.unique(arr)** and you can **increment each array value** and get the exact count of each value.

Answer (score 0):

Do it using MySQL query itself:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(option_name) AS option_count FROM $table WHERE poll_id = $poll_id GROUP BY option_name
```

This will return exactly as you wanted, and you can loop around the results to display it.